# 1inch swap function smart contract

Tags: solidity

Hello im trying make swap function but it always revert transaction ... function look like this :

```
function swap(bytes calldata _data, address _token, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20(_token).approve(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V4, _amount);
        (bool succ,) = address(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V4).call(_data);
        require(succ, "Failed to swap" );
    }
```

i pull swap data with python but it always revert ....

Comment: There's not enough details in your question. How is `_data` created? Can you provide an example? Do you have a failed transaction hash? Can you provide more details to reproduce the problem?

Comment: here is 1 reverted tx : https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x587e0c7735e7d914a5c2ffb6af16bd538e39ab1009b226a9d6ca30a66510c672
 and _data i get with python where i simply request swap url from 1 inch then i pull out swap data and those i want use in this swap function

Answer (score 2):

From the [trace](https://polygonscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0x587e0c7735e7d914a5c2ffb6af16bd538e39ab1009b226a9d6ca30a66510c672&type=gethtrace2) it is trying to use `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` as a ERC20 contract and it reverts.

```
{
  "type": "CALL",
  "from": "0xdfea147bc74cf3a418292d841de29bad81c81d8f",
  "to": "0x110b8a7023846d95978898a0462e515311fc6369",
  "value": "0x0",
  "gas": "0x8050",
  "gasUsed": "0x185f",
  "input": "0x4f74f0ed0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009a87c0252000000000000000000000000002ec255797fef7669fa243509b7a599121148ffba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180000000000000000000000000eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee0000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa841740000000000000000000000002ec255797fef7669fa243509b7a599121148ffba000000000000000000000000110b8a7023846d95978898a0462e515311fc6369000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b4fe00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012414284aab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000804000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee00000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d0e30db00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018414284aab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000440000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf127000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064d1660f990000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270000000000000000000000000cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e8580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a4b757fed6000000000000000000000000cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e8580000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf12700000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa841740000000000000000002dc6c02ec255797fef7669fa243509b7a599121148ffba000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018414284aab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000440000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa8417400000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064d1660f990000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa841740000000000000000000000001111111254fb6c44bac0bed2854e76f90643097d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cfee7c08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "error": "execution reverted",
  "calls": [
    {
      "type": "CALL",
      "from": "0x110b8a7023846d95978898a0462e515311fc6369",
      "to": "0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
      "value": "0x0",
      "gas": "0x66ee",
      "gasUsed": "0x0",
      "input": "0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000001111111254fb6c44bac0bed2854e76f90643097d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a0000",
      "output": "0x"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So how should i solve this when i want swap native token ? :)

Comment: @jednicka0 Just don't use `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` as a token address. If you explain how `_data` was created we could take another look.

Comment: in python i use : 
swap_req = requests.get(
    f'https://api.1inch.exchange/v4.0/{chain_id}'
    f'/swap?fromTokenAddress={token_in}'
    f'&toTokenAddress={token_out}'
    f'&amount={amount}'
    f'&fromAddress={s}'
    f'&slippage={slippage}').json()
then from response i pull out data ... problem is that 1inch dont take addres 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010 for MATIC only 0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: when i use 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010 for query data it says insufficient liquidity